# repeat number N times in a string in input file python ::

Tags: python, string, numpy

I am trying to repeat a number in an input file.dat N times,
I have read I could do N* string, however, as my input is not a string and it's a number in string then I convert it to numpy, so all I need is a way to repeat the input from the beginning

My code as below:

```
import numpy as np
with open('trial.dat', 'r') as f:
     data = f.readlines()
     data = [(d+' ')[:d.find('#')].rstrip() for d in data]
     x=data[0]
     y=np.fromstring(x,dtype=int, sep=',') # should be  y=[1 2 3 3 3 3 3]
```

#output error is :
DeprecationWarning: string or file could not be read to its end due to unmatched data; this will raise a ValueError in the future.
y=np.fromstring(x,dtype=int, sep=',')
Also asking if there is a way to add [] in the definition of input file ???

File .dat is the following:

```
1,2,3*5     # Can I add like [1,2,3*5] or I am also open to any other way to repeat number
```

Comment: What is the expected output? What is the error?

Comment: @BeChillerToo
Thank you for your feedback, below are the expected output and error 
Expected output is:
y=[1 2 3 3 3 3 3]

error is: DeprecationWarning: string or file could not be read to its end due to unmatched data; this will raise a ValueError in the future. y=np.fromstring(x,dtype=int, sep=',')

Comment: The `*` is not part of an integer, nor the given separator (which is `,`), so NumPy gets stuck at that point, since it doesn't know how to parse that character.

Comment: The "N* string" trick works in Python, not in an input file. So adding such a thing in your input file, whether it concerns strings or integers, will never work.

Comment: @9769953 
I do agree with you, but would you mind telling/suggesting me with an possible solution for repeating number in an input file ??

Comment: You read the numbers, *then* apply some code to duplicate one or more numbers multiple times. In  Python, the multiplication trick works with plain lists as well: `[5] * 3` results in `[5, 5, 5]` (with some caveat). So read the data from file without extras if possible, into a list, perform some slicing, list multiplication, then list concatenation.

Comment: If the `3*5` part is part of the input file and not part of the code, you'll have to write some smart parsing code yourself. For example, split a line on the comma, check each element for not being a single integer, and if not, parse that element accordingly.

Comment: @9769953
 I understand, but I need to write something like repeat or whatever in the input file 
I thought there is a way to repeat from the input file 
would be of great help if you know ... 

Anyway thank you

Comment: @9769953 It's part of input file, but bear in mind, it' s an changing variable as it's an input... so would be great if you could help me... as I am new to python

Comment: Probably easier if you somehow can restructure the input file into a more suitable format. A simple text file should be read as plain data, not something formulas inside of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = "1,2,3*5"

elements = data.split(",")
numbers = []
for elt in elements:
    if "*" in elt:
        n, mult = elt.split("*")
        numbers = numbers + [int(n)] * int(mult)
    else:
        numbers.append(int(elt))

print(numbers)
# [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, working!
also the other comment of Aayush Panda!

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answers, to explain what you have changed from the original code and why. Providing something for a user to copy and paste without context will not provide them with a learning experience, and makes the answer less useful for future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

As the commenters above mentioned, you don't need `numpy` to do this.

**Reading the data**

For just a single line, you could do something like this:

```
# read line from data file and make line into list delimiting by ','
with open('trial.dat', 'r') as f:
     data = f.readline().rstrip().split(',') 

newlist = []

# step trough items in list data
for d in data:
   if "*" in d: # if there's a "*" in the list 
      [a,b] = d.split('*') # split it on that value (e.g. d = "a*b" --> ["a", "b"]
      for i in range(int(a)):  # append "b" a times
         newlist.append(b)
   else: # if there's no "*" in list just append normally
      newlist.append(d)
print(newlist)
# ['1', '2', '5', '5', '5']
```

If you have multiple lines in your file, then I would ammend the above with something like this (I have just written your line in `trial.dat` 3 times for demonstration):

```
#if you have multiple lines
with open('trial_multi.dat', 'r') as f:
     data = [line.rstrip().split(',') for line in f.readlines()]

newlist = []

# step trough items in list data
for line in data:
   for d in line:
      if "*" in d: # if there's a "*" in the list 
         [a,b] = d.split('*') # split it on that value (e.g. d = "a*b" --> ["a", "b"]
         for i in range(int(a)):  # append "b" a times
            newlist.append(b)
      else: # if there's no "*" in list just append normally
         newlist.append(d)
print(newlist)
# ['1', '2', '5', '5', '5', '1', '2', '5', '5', '5', '1', '2', '5', '5', '5']
```

**Changing the type**

If you want arrays, you can simply do something like `newlist = np.array(newlist)`. If you want the values to be `float` or `int` type you can change the type with something like `newlist = [int(i) for i in newlist]`. Or you can combine them to make an array of `int` value with something like `newlist = np.array(newlist, dtype = 'int')`. Of course if you want `float` or some other type instead of `int` just change that in the above.

Answer (score 0):

```py
with open('trial.dat', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    data = data[0].split(',')  # Split input by commas
    output = ''

    for i in range(len(data)):  # Iterating through each group that was split by commas
        str_split = data[i].split('*')  # Splitting the split string by "*"

        if len(str_split) == 2:  # Checking if "*" was present in the split string
            output += str_split[0] * int(str_split[1])  # If "*" is present, add multiplied string to output
        else:
            output += str(data[i])

    output = list(map(int, list(output)))  # Convert list to array, the convert array elements to int

    print(output)
```

This should cut it. Instead of using vectors, I used array operations. The question was a bit confusing about the desired output, so this solution returns an array of integers.

Eg: `1,2,3*5` would return `[1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]`

Hopefully the comments help you understand the logic, which is relatively simple